# Cook/chill/freeze soy mince

Tags: freezing, soy

I cooked some chilled soy mince to use in a sauce - but I wanted to add it at the end, so I put it back in the refrigerator whilst the rest of the sauce cooked.

A couple of hours later I was ready to add it - added it to the sauce, all good. But now I'd like to freeze the sauce. Is this likely to be safe? I'm struggling to find anything that covers anything very similar to what I describe above.

Comment: Welcome! When you ask about „safe“, do you mean „food safety“ (spoiler: yes) or „will that work”?

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for the comment! I meant along the lines of "Is this likely to make me ill if I reheat it" kinda thing :D - so food safety for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dish has been made 'safe' by cooking and it is wrapped and chilled/frozen in a timely manner, all good.

Defrosting and reheating where it can come undone:
"The temperature danger zone is between 41°F and 135°F. food must pass through the temperature danger zone as quickly as possible. Keep hot food hot and cold food cold. Always use a thermometer to check internal food temperatures."

A large ziplock frozen flat is your friend here.